# How does the form of the electromagnetic wave equation indicate relativistic invariance?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

One question in a test I am going to take is: How does the form of the electromagnetic wave equations
$$ \Delta \phi - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = - 4\pi \rho $$
indicate relativistic invariance?

Is there a way to directly conclude this?

Comment: can't you just make lorentz transformation and see wheter the form of the equation changed?

Comment: Yes, but the exact question is: "What does the form of the equations tell you about their validity regarding relativity." The only answer I can think would be that they can be written in a covariant form..

Comment: Is it not written in a covariant form? On the right hand side is just d'Alembert operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalars are Lorentz invariant, also the differential operator (d'Alembert).

Edit:
The question contains only one component of the EM field not a scalar/anything else. So for the answer see the comments below.

Comment: Does the same apply for the equation for the vector potential?

Comment: Well, for a simple vector field: yes. For the EM vector porential: I think only for a Lorentz-invariant gauge.

Comment: Yeah, for the 4-potential only Lorenz-gauge condition gives a manifest Lorentz invariant equation, i.e., the wave equation.

Comment: The scalar potential is not a Lorentz-scalar, neither is the charge density. The are the time-component of a 4-vector.

Comment: Sorry, the question was a little bit misleading.

Comment: Ok, so the answer would be: "The wave equations can be expressed as a 4-vector which is Lorentz-covariant."?

Comment: A little bit more precise: The wave equation is a 4-vector equation with source term. And yes, it is better written in covariant form. Like this: DA^m=kJ^m. Where D is the d'Alembert operator, m is Lorentz index, J is the 4-current, k is constant. And also needs a gauge constraint.

Comment: Any wave equation $\Box A^{\alpha} =B^{\alpha}$  (A (B) can be a scalar, a 4-vector, a tensor, a spinor etc.)  is Lorentz-covariant as long as $A$ and$B$ transform in the same way under Lorentz-transformation. In the particular case as the scalar potential and the charge density are both time-components of a 4-vector they transform in the same way. But it might be more interesting to show why the d'Alembert-operator is Lorentz-covariant (whereas Laplace is not).